# How do I build urls and enforce integrity?

Tags: php, url, zend-framework, zend-framework2

What is the best way to build url's and insure they maintain accuracy using zend framework 2?

I have a url that is www.foo/james/bond/23.  The queries I am running to populate the data on the page are based on the third parameter (23).  However currently there is no integrity to the url.

I can change the url to www.foo/james/bond/22 and the first (james) and last (bond) name remain the same while the page now gives me information regarding person 22.

I can change the url to www.foo/ja/bon/22 and I still get to james bonds webpage because the queries key on the last number.

How can I enforce url integrity?

Thanks,
M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sticking with your example `/james/bond/23`, after loading the data for the object with ID 23, you need to check that the other data in the URL matches. If not, you either 301 redirect to the correct URL, or 404, depending on your requirements. You can either do this check in the controller (easiest), or use a custom route class that handles the route matching and the integrity check (more complicated).

Comment: This is what I was thinking about.  Using something like array_dif?  If diff > 1 return to correct param.

Comment: if(array_values($urlArray)<>array_values($proArray)) worked thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're only using the third route parameter in your query. If you add all three, you should get what you're after.